# Struct layout and type size?

Tags: c#, layout, types, casting

Is this struct guaranteed to be 10 bytes on all modern architectures?

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
public struct NavPoint
{
    public ushort type;
    public ushort px;
    public ushort py;
    public ushort rootIndex;
    public byte nNeighbours;
    public byte nEntrances;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. .NET in general has official standards regardless of user's platform and hardware. Mono-framework also follows the standards of .NET Framework and .NET Core. To prove your question, you can either use an unsafe [sizeof](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/sizeof) operator, or use [Marshal.SizeOf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.sizeof?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.5#System_Runtime_InteropServices_Marshal_SizeOf_System_Object_)

[Marshal.SizeOf:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.sizeof?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.5#System_Runtime_InteropServices_Marshal_SizeOf_System_Object_)

```cs
var test = new NavPoint {type = 1, px = 2, py = 3, rootIndex = 5, nNeighbours = 0x1, nEntrances = 0x2 };
Console.Write(System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(k)); // 10
```

[sizeof:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/sizeof)

```cs
unsafe {
    Console.Write(sizeof(NavPoint)); // 10
}
```